# Unable to apply regex on all columns of csv

Tags: python, regex, pandas

```
Input : T1_col1 T2_col2 MANDT   BUKRS   LIFNR
           NULL         900     1100    1000000010
           NULL         900     1100    1000000044

Columns: T1_col1, T2_col2, MANDT, BUKRS, LIFNR

Output:             T1_col1 T2_col2 MANDT   BUKRS   LIFNR
                0                     900   1100    DDDDDDDDDD
                1                     900   1100    DDDDDDDDDD


Code:
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df = df.replace('[A-Za-z]','N', regex=True).replace('\d','D', regex=True)
df.to_csv('Output.csv')
```

As it can be seen that the columns named MANDT, BUKRS didnt get replaced. I want all the columns to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what version of python you're using, mine doesn't have a `regex` option in replace. Nevertheless, this should work:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('[A-Za-z]','N').str.replace('\d','D'))
```

My guess is that some of your columns aren't formatted as strings but as digits, on which the replace won't work.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: You are right. Those columns are of int64 type. How should I deal with non-string columns?

Comment: When you want to perform regex, you have to work on strings, therefore what you can do is changing the type of your series before applying your regex: `df['MANDT'] = df['MANDT'].astype(str)`

Comment: Or if you don't change it before, it is inside the code line in my answer: `x.astype(str)`

Comment: Thanks! It worked if I applied it before applying my regex.